# Create a three post column Blogger template

Tags: css, html, templates, blogger

I am trying to create my own blogger template. I want to have posts on three column. I tried to ad float on the post component but it create bugs.

My blog with float : https://words-deep-water.blogspot.fr/

The code is here : https://words-deep-water.blogspot.fr/2017/03/version1.html

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't much understand from the link you posted.But if you are looking to divide a row into 3 equal columns to show the posts, you might want to have a look at this:

http://materializecss.com/grid.html.

```
 <style>
  .row {width : 100%}
  .col s4 {width : 33.33%}
 </style>
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col s4">This div takes 33.33% width of the outer div. POST 1</div>
      <div class="col s4">This div takes 33.33% width of the outer div. POST 2</div>
      <div class="col s4">This div takes 33.33% width of the outer div.POST 3</div>
 </div>
```

Using something similar to above code,you might be able to achieve your functionality. 
Explanation of the code: We have a div with class row which gives it width 100%. And all the inner divs inside it will take 33.33% width of the outer div giving us three divs of equal width.

Answer (score 0):

Better try to use 3 column responsive blogger template. There are many free responsive templates available for blogger users. If you added extra style code then it may affect mobile users.